# Iframe changing according to javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, select, iframe, src

I'm attempting to reload an iframe when a onChange event occurs

heres what i got in javascript tags in the header

```
`
```

function getSchedule(oEvent)
{
    var n = document.getElementById("wantedTherapist");
    var newn = n.options[n.selectedIndex].value; 
    window.frames['schedule'].src = "schedule.php?therapist="+newn;
}

`

and then my iframe tag

```
iframe id="schedule" name="schedule" src="schedule.php"></iframe>
```

and finally my select box

```
<select id="wantedTherapist" name="wantedTherapist" onchange="getSchedule(Event)">
?php
            $query = "SELECT
                    therapistTable.*
                    FROM
                    therapistTable
                    WHERE
                    therapistTable.activated = 'true'
                    ";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
            while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            extract($array);
            echo "<option value=\"$username\">$username - $city</option>";
            }
?
</select>
```

i took the arrows off php tags and the first arrow off iframe so that it would show in question. Its loading the schedule.php in the iframe but not sending it the variable, what am i doing wrong?? thank you for any advice ahead of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the URL of the iFrame being set to? You can confirm this (in Firefox) by right clicking in the iFrame and selecting "Open Frame in New Window"

If the URL is `schedule.php?therapist=`, then the error is with the code you've posted here. If the URL contains a value for `therapist`, for example, `schedule.php?therapist=bob`, then the error is in `schedule.php`.

Comment: hmm the url of the frame is schedule.php no matter what the selected item is

Comment: so that means there's a problem with my js

Comment: ive heard that using window.frames['schedule'].src is a better way to go than document.getelementbyid because more browsers support this

Comment: do i need to perhaps not set the src of the iframe in the initial load?

Comment: it works with `document.getElementById("schedule").src = "schedule.php?therapist="+newn;` instead of `window.frames['schedule'].src = "schedule.php?therapist="+newn` so i guess ill just use that thank you sir!

Comment: Looks like you figured it out on your own. Glad I could help... although I didn't do much. Nice work!